# How to use the form to insert an image using its address (uri) and get the image on the page? .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I am currently working on the NET MAUI project and I want to add a recipe for a dish to the database via a form. I added the name of the dish, the ingredients, but what I still want to add is the image. How do I pass uri of the image and get it on the page where the dishes are listed?

```
   <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label Text="Name" FontSize="16"/>
        <Entry Text="{Binding RecipeDetails.Name}" Placeholder="Meal"/>
   </VerticalStackLayout>
```

This is how I add the name and ingredients for the dish. In the model I have defined the name of the dish, the ingredients and I will define the image as a string as well.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is the user typing in an image url?  Or taking a picture with the camera?  Or something else?

Comment: @Jason - It's a basic uri of an image from the internet. e.g. https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/wide-angle-shot-single-tree-growing-clouded-sky-during-sunset-surrounded-by-grass_181624-22807.jpg

Comment: you can display an image directly from a url.  I'm a little unclear on where you are stuck.  The docs cover this expicitly: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#download-images

Comment: Well, as I said, I have a form with which I add data about a dish. I need to pass uri of the image in the app (as a user, you can type name, ingridients and paste uri of the image from the internet) and the image should be displayed on the page where the dishes are listed.

Comment: just save the url as a string in your model

Answer (score 0):

you can use a url as an `ImageSource`

```
<Image Source="{Binding RecipeDetails.ImageUrl}" ... />
```

Comment: Thank you for advice - should I have entry + ImageSource, cause I need to insert (copy/paste) image uri somewhere...?

Comment: just have an Entry for the user to paste the url into.  If you also want to display the image on the form, add an Image too.  Its entirely up to you.